# Derive Matrix from Matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm converting a paper in code. At some point I feel to have all the elements to derive a matrix but I cannot do it. I have both $\Sigma$ and $\Psi$ and $\Gamma$. Someone can help me in deriving the matrix $\hat{\Sigma}$ exploiting the relation below and also in understanding what kind of decomposition is the paper talking about:

[image]

Comment: Do you also have $\Gamma$?

Comment: Yes I have $\Gamma$ too

Comment: Do we have $\Gamma = \pmatrix{\Sigma\\ \Psi_Z}$?

Comment: @Nic Also, could you please tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it I haven't tried anything, the paper suggests decomposition, but I know only about SVD and Cholesky but I feel they are not the right tools. Yes @Ben we have the equality you mentioned $\Gamma = \pmatrix{\Sigma\\ \Psi_Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rephrase what seems to be happening: we are given $\Sigma$ (size $m \times (m + K)$) and $\Psi$ (size $K \times (m+K)$), and we need to find a matrix $\hat \Sigma$ of size $m \times (m + K)$ such that the following equations hold:
$$
\hat \Sigma \hat \Sigma' = \Sigma\Sigma', \quad \hat \Sigma\Psi' = 0
$$
I cannot know what the authors of the paper have in mind. However, here is one approach to solving this problem.

First, find a matrix $L$ of size $m \times m$ such that $LL' = \Sigma \Sigma'$. One way to do this is using the [Choelsky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). Next, find a matrix $U$ with orthonormal rows (i.e. such that $UU' = I$) that satisfies $U\Psi = 0$. This can be done using the "full" QR-decomposition. In particular, we have
$$
\Psi' = \pmatrix{Q_1 & Q_2} \pmatrix{R\\0}\implies 
\pmatrix{Q_1'\\ Q_2'} \Psi' = \pmatrix{R\\0} \implies
\begin{cases}
Q_1' \Psi' = R,\\
Q_2' \Psi' = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
In the above, $Q_1$ is $(m+K) \times K$ (the same shape as $\Psi'$) and $Q_2$ is $(m+K)\times m$. With that, we can take $U = Q_2'$. Finally, we find that $\hat \Sigma = LU$ satisfies the required conditions. Indeed, we have
$$
\hat \Sigma \hat \Sigma' = (LU)(LU)' = L UU' L' = LL' = \Sigma \Sigma',\\
\hat \Sigma \Psi' = L(U\Psi') = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to implement it.

Comment: in my understanding $U$ is $K\times m+K$ and $L$ is $m\times m$, so I'm still not able to find $\hat{\Sigma}=LU$ right?

Comment: @Nic I made a mistake when writing the matrix sizes. $U$ has shape $m \times (m + K)$, so the multiplication $LU$ is fine.

Comment: Typo: where it says $U U' = 0$ it should say $U U' = I$

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Thanks